# Device isn't compatible for newer AND older phones in Google Play store

Tags: android, android-studio

I just released my app on the google play store. My testing device is an older nexus 5 running 6.0.1, but I have a friend with a new android phone, and the app is not available for either phone on the play store.

There is no maxSdkVersion, and the mindSdkVersion is 17, which should work on 6.0.1 according to the android versions.

**Here is my manifest:**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />


<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
    android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication">
    <activity android:name=".LauncherActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".LoginActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".RegisterActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".ForgotPasswordActivity" />
    <activity
        android:name=".MainNavigationActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main_navigation"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />

    <receiver
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service
        android:name=".services.PushGcmListenerService"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <service
        android:name=".services.PushInstanceIDListenerService"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <service
        android:name=".services.RegistrationIntentService"
        android:exported="false" />

</application>
```

**And here is my gradle:**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "#####"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        multiDexEnabled = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'

// 3rd part
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
compile 'br.com.simplepass:loading-button-android:1.12.0'
compile 'org.apache.directory.studio:org.apache.commons.io:2.4'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'


compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'

//required support lib modules
implementation "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0"
implementation "com.android.support:support-annotations:26.1.0"

compile 'com.github.pavlospt:circleview:1.3'

compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:12.0.0'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
//compile group: "com.twilio.sdk", name: "twilio", version: "7.18.0"
```

Comment: When uploading your app to Google you can specify which devices, countries, operators, ... your app will be available. As your manifest does not contain much restrictions I would focus on that part if it prevents your app from being accessible in PlayStore.

Comment: Tell more information about your friend's device: manufacturer, model, android version etc.

Comment: Update: I am seeing "0 supported by this app" in the google play console. (not surprising)

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION:

```
compile 'org.apache.directory.studio:org.apache.commons.io:2.4'
```

This reference had to be removed and a new APK published. After it was removed the Google Play console recognized 12k+ devices for the new build.